# How to Fix : 42601: syntax error at or near "value" When Try To Access Hangfire Dashboard

Tags: postgresql, .net-6.0, hangfire

I Use Hangfire With Postgresql Storage in .net-6.0 and install this package : Hangfire.PostgreSql version 1.9.10

This is My Code In Program.cs :

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddHangfire(config => config.UsePostgreSqlStorage(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("HangfireConnection")));
builder.Services.AddHangfireServer();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseHangfireDashboard();
```

This is My Connection string in webconfig :

```
    "ConnectionStrings": {
    "HangfireConnection": "Host=db1.motorazmasamin.com;Port=***;Database=Hangfire;Username=***;Password=***"
},
```

When Type Dashboard URL(http://localhost/hangfire) , Return This Error:

> {"data":null,"status":-1,"message":"42601: syntax error at or near "value"\r\n\r\nPOSITION: 59","statusCode":"500"}

[Show Error Image in Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1S88.jpg)

But When Change Connection String to SQL Server and change Package To Hangfire.SqlServer , It's Correct!

Comment: Hy, welcome to Stack Overflow, please [don't upload text, table or error message as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). 
Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. 
Also see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

This issue was fixed in version 1.19.11. For more details, visit https://github.com/hangfire-postgres/Hangfire.PostgreSql/pull/280/files